# Is it possible to use a form to submit a list in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like users of the site to be upload multiple images at the same time up to a maximum of 5. I created all of my `ViewModels` and also the `[HttpPost]` method that will handle the list of images and iterate through each, saving them.

My question is: How do I receive that list in the Post method?

I have the following code for my ViewModels:

```
public class ImageCreateViewModel
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }

    public int CollectionId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a description of the photo.")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please attach an image.")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase Image { get; set; }

    public string Location { get; set; }

    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class ImagesCreateViewModel : ImageCreateViewModel
{
    public List<ImageCreateViewModel> Images { get; set; }

    public MyEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new MyEnumerator(this);
    }
}


public class MyEnumerator
{
    int index;
    ImagesCreateViewModel imagesCreateViewModel;

    public MyEnumerator(ImagesCreateViewModel imagesCreateViewModel)
    {
        this.imagesCreateViewModel = imagesCreateViewModel;
        index = -1;
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        index++;
        return (index < imagesCreateViewModel.Images.Count());
    }

    public ImageCreateViewModel Current
    {
        get
        {
            return (imagesCreateViewModel.Images[index]);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateImages(ImagesCreateViewModel imagesEditViewModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(imagesEditViewModel);
    }

    foreach (ImageCreateViewModel imageCreateViewModel in imagesEditViewModel)
    {
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string serverPath = Server.MapPath("~");
        string contentPath = String.Format("Content\\{0}\\Content\\Images\\{1}", Helper.Helper.ResolveBrand(), fileName);
        string imagePath = serverPath + contentPath;

        bool success = Helper.Helper.SaveImage(imagePath, imageCreateViewModel.Image.InputStream);

        if (success)
        {
            Image image = new Image
            {
                Collection = ds.Single<Collection>(c => c.CollectionId == imageCreateViewModel.CollectionId),
                Description = imageCreateViewModel.Description,
                Location = contentPath,
                Order = Helper.Helper.GetImageOrder(imageCreateViewModel.CollectionId)
            };

            ds.InsertOnSubmit<Image>(image);
            ds.SubmitChanges();
        }

        else
            //TODO: Write Error to them
            success = false;
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Collection");

}
```

But when I generate a View for this method it only has the abilty to manipulate one image at a time (which I have to edit to allow them to upload an image):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Image</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Image)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Image)
            <input type="file" name="Image" />
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: Don't know for ASP specifically, but in general you can pass arrays in POST by setting the names for your fields as array identifiers. i.e. `<input type="file" name="Image[]" />` This works in PHP, and I imagine you can do the same or similar in ASP. Think about if you coded this - you would have `Image[] = someImage; Image[] = someOtherImage; Image[] = anotherImage`, which leaves you with an array of images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code I used on my site to upload multiple images:

---

OK, so this is a simple example on how to do it. The end result:

[image]

The HTML markup is a simple form, with a submit button.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="form-field">
        <p>Select pictures:</p>
        <div class="upload-container">
            <div class="upload">
                <input type="file" name="files" id="file1" /> 
                <img src="@Url.Content("~/Public/images/delete.png")" alt="Remove picture." />
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </div>
}
```

We also needs some jQuery magic so that every time someone adds an image, we let them also add in more as needed. A user can upload N images. We're using the `on()` method so that the events bind on every newly created element.

Notice the name of the inputs added are "files", the same name we use in the ActionMethod.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var currentImage = 1;
        $("body").on("change", "input[name='files']", function () {
            var pathToRemoveIcon = "@Url.Content("~/Public/images/delete.png")";
            currentImage = currentImage + 1;
            var htmlToAppend = '<div class="upload"><input type="file" name="files" id="file' + currentImage + '" /><img src="' + pathToRemoveIcon + '" alt="Remove picture." /></div>';
            $('.upload-container').append(htmlToAppend);
        }).on("click", ".upload img", function () {
            if ($(this).parent().siblings().length > 0) {
                $(this).parent().remove();    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And finally the controller code we receive the model that we want to bind, and also the enumerable of files:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Verify that the user selected a file
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    // extract only the filename
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                    // etc.
                }
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really work as they have to add other information in as well.

Comment: @danRhul: Edited the signature of the ActionMethod to illustrate how to bind a typical POCO model, and the files uploaded. :) This works well and I use it all the time on websites.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but you are going to have do more work than just auto scaffolding the view. The following is a blog post by Phil Haack that details how to build HTML views that are friendly to ModelBinding in MVC and collections.

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Another post by Scott Hansleman on the topic.
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will transfer over to generating the model properly, but if you are able to use HTML5, then you can do use the `input multiple` attribute for allowing more than one input. It isnt horribly pretty in chrome I will admit, though

[Here is the documentation](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.file.html)

[And, here is a decent example that makes things a little prettier](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have updated my answer to point to the documentation from w3 for now. I will see if I can find a different interactive example. Please remove the downvotes :)

Comment: Yup, just did. Make sure to tag people with @ when you respond though, cause otherwise they don't get your reply unless they are the poster. I just came back to check if you had fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

MVC will allow you to accept multiple file uploads in an action by accepting a list of `HttpPostedFileBase` objects.  You will need to make sure that all your file upload controls have the same name as the argument to your action method.

```
public ActionResult UploadFiles(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can upload multiple files with one post.

Simply set your fileupload name with a different one for each of them and in your controller do a foreach in `Request.Files`. Something similar to that:

```
foreach (var file in Request.Files)
{
  if (file.ContentLength > 0)
  ... do something ...

}
```

[Here a sample](http://forums.asp.net/post/4860286.aspx)